# In Flutter, I aim to display dates in the format "dd-MM-yyyy," while ensuring that they are saved in the database using the format "yyyy-MM-dd."how?

Tags: flutter, pgadmin

```dart
 Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(
                                  controller: dateController,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Start Date',
                                    hintText: 'Select Start Date ',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  ),
                                  readOnly: true,
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    var pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                                      context: context,
                                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                                    );
                                    _autoSave();

                                    if (pickedDate != null) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        var formattedDate =
                                            DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                                                .format(pickedDate);
                                        dateController.text =
                                            formattedDate.split(' ')[0];
                                      });
                                    } else {
                                      print("Please Select the Date");
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

above code for start date...

```
 Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(
                                  controller: endDateController,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'End Date',
                                    hintText: 'Select End Date ',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  ),
                                  readOnly: true,
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    var pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                                      context: context,
                                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                                    );
                                    _autoSave();

                                    if (pickedDate != null) {
                                      final formattedPickedDate =
                                          DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                                              .format(pickedDate);
                                      final startDateTime =
                                          DateTime.parse(dateController.text);
                                      if (isEndDateValid(
                                          startDateTime, pickedDate)) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          endDateController.text =
                                              formattedPickedDate;
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        // Show an error message to the user
                                        showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            return AlertDialog(
                                              title: Text('Invalid End Date'),
                                              content: Text(
                                                  'End date must be on or after the start date.'),
                                              actions: [
                                                ElevatedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                                  },
                                                  child: Text('OK'),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            );
                                          },
                                        );
                                      }
                                    } else {
                                      print("Please Select the Date");
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

this is for end date.

i am autosaving the data ..

```
 Future<void> _autoSave() async {
    String abnormal = _isYesSelected ? 'yes' : 'no';

    // Cancel the existing timer if it's running
    _saveTimer?.cancel();
    const Duration delayDuration = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _saveTimer = Timer(delayDuration, () async {
      try {
        String displayedstartDate = dateController.text;
        DateTime parsedstartDate =
            DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(displayedstartDate);
        String databasestartDate =
            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(parsedstartDate);

        String displayedendDate = endDateController.text.trim();
        print("End Date Text: $displayedendDate");
        if (displayedendDate.isNotEmpty) {
          print("Displayed End Date: $displayedendDate");

          try {
            DateTime parsedEndDate =
                DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(displayedendDate);
            String databaseendDate =
                DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(parsedEndDate);

            // Rest of your code that uses databaseendDate

          } catch (e) {
            print("Error parsing end date: $e");
          }
        } else {
          print("End Date is empty or invalid.");
          // Handle the case where the end date is not provided.
        }
        // if (displayedendDate.isNotEmpty) {
        //   print(
        //       "Displayed End Date: $displayedendDate"); // Print the displayed date to check its value

        //   try {
        //     DateTime parsedEndDate =
        //         DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(displayedendDate);
        //     // Rest of your code
        //   } catch (e) {
        //     print("Error parsing end date: $e");
        //   }
        // } else {
        //   print("End Date is empty or invalid.");
        //   // Handle the case where the end date is not provided.
        // }
        // print("Displayed End Date: $displayedendDate");
        DateTime parsedendDate =
            DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(displayedendDate);
        String databaseendDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(parsedendDate);

        EInspectionData savedData = EInspectionData(
          status: 0,
          inspectionId: '', // Leave this empty if it's a new inspection
          instypeid: _localCardData['instypeid'],
          commanDepartment:
              SelectedValues().selectedItems, // List of selected departments
          railways: _selectedRailway?.rlyUnitCode ?? 0,
          // railways: 9,
          division: _selecteddivision?.rlyUnitCode ??
              0, // Replace with actual default value

          // division: 131,

          // start_date: dateController.text,
          start_date: databasestartDate,
          start_time: startTimeController.text,
          // end_date: endDateController.text,
```

how to do this review my code and implement logic

Comment: When storing the data, save the datetime and just parse it to whatever formart you need when displaying it.

Comment: You already know to use `DateFormat.parse` and `DateFormat.format` with appropriate format-strings.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: start date i am able to select in my app but not end date